# Jupyter notebook server: restrict access to selected IPs

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm setting up a jupyter notebook server on my LAN and I'd like to restrict it to only several IPs in the network.

I followed the configuration setup: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html#notebook-server-security and now have at least a password security.
But I'd like to make it more secure and only limit to selected IP addresses in my network.

Details about the hosting machine: *Windows 10 and Anaconda*

My `jupyter_notebook_config.py`:

```
# Set options for certfile, ip, password, and toggle off
# browser auto-opening
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/absolute/path/to/your/certificate/fullchain.pem'
c.NotebookApp.keyfile = u'/absolute/path/to/your/certificate/privkey.pem'
# Set ip to '*' to bind on all interfaces (ips) for the public server
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
#c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = ''
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:bcd259ccf...<your hashed password here>'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False

# It is a good idea to set a known, fixed port for server access
c.NotebookApp.port = 9999
```

I expected to set a list of IPs in `c.NotebookApp.ip`, but didn't work.
Could you help me with that please?

Comment: You could use a reverse proxy server like nginx. That will make it easier to achieve this and other security features.

Comment: Thank you @Yuvraj. It's a bit out of my scope, but if it's the only solution, I'd dig into it.

Comment: Added an answer with little more details to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do this just via jupyter config, but IMO doing it with a reverse proxy server (like nginx) would be a better idea and can provide more security features.

An example here
`nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream ml {
        server jupyterhub:8000;
    }

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
        allow  192.168.1.1/24;


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://ml;

            proxy_redirect   off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            # websocket headers
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
    }

}
```

You can configure to listen on any port `8080` here and even use stuff like SSL.

You can find more reference here:
https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/config-proxy.html
https://hands-on.cloud/how-to-setup-jupyter-behind-nginx-proxy/
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/